# How can I retrieve a dump file after BSOD?

Tags: bsod, dump

I am running Windows XP and my system is repeatedly crashing after I run a particular application. I have a coworker who has informed me to get the "dump file" and send it to him so that he can analyze it.

Where can I find this dump file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx)
You can find the dumps at: `c:\windows\minidump`